# Importing a folder of images using Scikit io module

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I am trying to learn image processing using scikit image packages. I know I will eventually need to import folders with a large number of images eventually. I started by specifying the path of each file individually, which worked fine and I was able to produce the array I was hoping.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from skimage import io
from skimage import viewer
fID1 = 'C:/Users/keand/Documents/Strader Lab/HJ pictures/PictureB.jpg'
fID2 = 'C:/Users/keand/Documents/Strader Lab/HJ pictures/PictureA.jpg'
root1 = io.imread(fID1)
root2 = io.imread(fID2)
```

I then tried to use the example from scikit's documentation to load a folder.

```
>>> import os
>>> from natsort import natsorted, ns
>>> from skimage import io
>>> list_files = os.listdir('.')
>>> list_files
['01.png', '010.png', '0101.png', '0190.png', '02.png']
>>> list_files = natsorted(list_files)
>>> list_files
['01.png', '02.png', '010.png', '0101.png', '0190.png']
>>> image_list = []
>>> for filename in list_files:
...   image_list.append(io.imread(filename))
```

This is my recreation:

```
import os
from natsort import natsorted,ns
from skimage import io
from skimage.io import imread
listFiles = os.listdir('C:/Users/keand/Documents/Strader Lab/HJ pictures')
# listFiles = os.listdir('./HJ pictures')
print(listFiles)
listFiles = natsorted(listFiles)
print(listFiles)
imageList = []
for filename in listFiles:
    imageList.append(io.imread(filename))
```

When I run this, I get the following:

```
runfile('C:/Users/keand/Documents/Strader Lab/ImageProcessing.py', wdir='C:/Users/keand/Documents/Strader Lab')
['PictureA.jpg', 'PictureB.jpg']
['PictureA.jpg', 'PictureB.jpg']
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\keand\Documents\Strader Lab\ImageProcessing.py", line 31, in <module>
    imageList.append(io.imread(filename))

  File "C:\Users\keand\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_io.py", line 48, in imread
    img = call_plugin('imread', fname, plugin=plugin, **plugin_args)

  File "C:\Users\keand\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\manage_plugins.py", line 207, in call_plugin
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\keand\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_plugins\imageio_plugin.py", line 10, in imread
    return np.asarray(imageio_imread(*args, **kwargs))

  File "C:\Users\keand\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\functions.py", line 265, in imread
    reader = read(uri, format, "i", **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\keand\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\functions.py", line 172, in get_reader
    request = Request(uri, "r" + mode, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\keand\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\request.py", line 124, in __init__
    self._parse_uri(uri)

  File "C:\Users\keand\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\request.py", line 260, in _parse_uri
    raise FileNotFoundError("No such file: '%s'" % fn)

FileNotFoundError: No such file: 'C:\Users\keand\Documents\Strader Lab\PictureA.jpg'
```

Can someone please help me figure out why I am getting the FileNoFoundError when it recognizes the name of the image?

Below are some of the troubleshooting steps I have tried.

1. Rename the files
2. Make sure the python script and file are in the same directory
3. Printing listFiles after it is created
4. Adding +name to the end of the line first defining listFiles
5. Importing numpy and matplotlib in case there were any dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It is a lot easier to use the io.imread_collection function of the io module. This will create a collection of images which are store as an nd array.

```
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.io import imread_collection
dirName = 'C:/Users/keand/Documents/Strader_Lab/Image_Processing/HJ_Pictures/*.jpg'
collection = imread_collection(dirName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the error message, the filepath you are trying to load does not exist.

The images are not in your working directory. You have to load them by filepath, not filename.

```
import os
scr = 'C:/Users/keand/Documents/Strader Lab/HJ pictures'
listFiles = [os.path.join(src, f) for f in os.listdir(src)]
print(listFiles)
```

I prefer to use pathlib library:

```
from pathlib import Path 
scr = Path('C:/Users/keand/Documents/Strader Lab/HJ pictures')
listFiles = [f.resolve() for f in src.glob("*.jpg")]
print(listFiles)
```